# eclipse(python)でnumpyを使いたい

Tags: python, eclipse

eclipseでpythonをやってます。numpyを`C:\Python34\Scripts`にいれてみたところ、コマンドプロンプトでは下のコードは通るんですが、eclipseではエラーになります

```
from numpy import array
A=array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B=array([[5,6],[7,8]])
C=A+B
print A,B,C
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\~~~~~\Users\�ɖ�\eclipse\pleiades\pleiades\workspace\Python �\Statistics\Matrix_ABC.py", line 6, in ?
    from numpy import array
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\numpy\__init__.py", line 161
    from .version import git_revision as __git_revision__
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

このエラーの意味と解決法を教えてください。
プログラミング初心者なので何が原因か全くわからないので、情報不足だと思います、すいません。

Comment: numpyはどのように入れましたか? SourceForgeにあるWindows用のインストーラーでしょうか？それともソースから自力? numpy/version.pyはインストール時に自動生成されるファイルで、内容を確認してみてください。

Comment: 今更の気もしますが、ユーザー名が漢字とかではありませんか? しっかり、文字化けしてるようです。

Answer (score 1):

なんで~git_revision~のエラーが起きているのかはよく分かりませんが、とりあえず、以下のコマンドでnumpyをインストールし直してみたらいかがですか？

```
$ pip install numpy
```

python 3.x系なら以下のコマンドかもしれません。

```
$ pip3 install numpy
```

僕は今の所この方法で、eclipse上でnumpyを動かす事ができています。